# How to open a URL in incognito window using js?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any method to open a link in a new incognito/private window using js?

Found this but it only works from within the extensions.

```
windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

But I want to open a specific page in incognito mode when the user clicks on a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Browsers provide no API that would make that possible outside of an extension.